# Got confused with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I just reached pointers in my textbook but it doesn't explain good enough, so i need some help.

I know what pointers are and what they do. for example i understand the following example very well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num = 5;
    int *point;

    point = &num;

    *point = 8;

    printf("%d %d", num, *point);

    return 0;
}
```

point is pointing to num (storing num's address as its value). and then i'm dereferencing point to change the original value of num.

now consider the sightly modified version of the same example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int num = 5;
    int *point;

    point = 8;

    printf("point: %d\n", point);

    printf("sum (%d) = num (%d)+ point (%d)", num+point, num, point);

    return 0;
}
```

**I have a couple of questions:**

1- why is it even possible to assign a normal value (8) to a pointer (point)? aren't pointers supposed to store only addresses to other stuff? what is happening in line 8?

2- i compiled the code and for the second printf it shows :
sum (28) = num (5) + point (8)
why sum equals to 28? 5+8 is 13. what is happening?

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain a lot about the second program? gcc gives 4 separate warnings when I compile the code.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks with mingw32 and it compiles with warnings... but it compiles. Anyway I could really use some answers for my questions.

Comment: The fact is that the code produces undefined behavior. There's simplistic answers about how pointers are like ints, but such answers aren't really correct and the truth depends a lot on a detailed reading of the language standard.

Comment: The attitude “it compiles with warnings... but it compiles” will get you into a lot of trouble. I hope that the answers here help you understand the warnings! Warnings mean “this is probably an error”, and that is almost always true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can point `point` at memory address 8 (or 0x00000008). It is equivalent to `point = (int*)8;` I get a friendly `<Unable to read memory>` error because I'm using a c++ and I assume it's protecting me from my foolishness.

Why does 5 + 8 = 28? If you add a number n to a pointer of type T, you move this pointer by n elements of type T. Your machine is dealing with 32 bit ints , which are of size 4 bytes, so 8 + ( 5 * 4) = 28.

Comment: But i'm printing it on the first printf with %d and it shows 8. isn't %d for integers and not memory location??

Comment: @ufosecret Are you expecting %d to dereference your pointer? I think it just shows their int representation.

Comment: `%d` is just to format an integral number. If you give it a pointer value (an address), it'll just print the value of that address in decimal form.

Comment: To be clear, `point = 8;` is illegal but some compilers have an extension to treat it as `point = (int *)8;`

Comment: @ufosecret using `%d` with a pointer causes undefined behaviour. use `%p` to print it.

Comment: @ufosecret and what Matt means, is that one of the possible outcomes is that it works correctly, but the behavior is not defined by the standard.

Comment: `5 + (int*)8` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

In your second example you are assigning 8 to your pointer. I hope you got a good warning from your compiler. But you can assign 8. Just don't dereference it. You'll probably get a segmentation fault or worse. The sum of num+point makes perfect sense. It's called pointer arithmetic. point is a pointer to integer. An int on your machine is 4 bytes. The sum of num + point is (5 * sizeof(int)) + 8, which is 28 on your system.

Comment: `5 + (int*)8` makes perfect sense but it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Anonymous: You'd better tell that to the kernel and embedded guys. 40 years of work down the drain.

Answer (score 4):

Because virtually all C compilers implement pointers as integral numbers to support pointer arithmetic.

```
int arr[10];
int *ip = arr;

arr[2] = 42;      // this is equivalent to:
*(ip + 2) = 42;   // or
*(2 + ip) = 42;
```

Let's say, `&arr[0]` (the address of the first element of the integer array `arr`) is `0xcafe0000`. Let's assume one `int` value takes up 4 bytes in memory. Then `&arr[1]` is at `0xcafe0004`, `&arr[2]` is at `0xcafe0008`, and so on at 4-byte increments.

The compiler sees this:

```
int i = arr[5];       // which is equivalent to:
int j = *(arr + 5);
```

and take the address `0xcafee0000`, and add `(5 * sizeof(int))`, which comes out to `0xcafee0028` before dereferencing it.

Which is why when you cast any ol' integral number to a pointer type, say:

```
int *p = (int*) 8;
```

And then add it:

```
p = p + 5;    // p := 28
```

The compiler will take `p`'s value, and add it to the operand `5` **times the size of `int`**.

Comment: `p = p + 5` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

A pointer is a number, just like an `int` is a number. Assigning a hard coded value to a pointer is legal but a warning is issued

```
point = 8;
```

but meaningless unless you are working with an embedded system and know what is at that address 8.

Although your program survived memory access restrictions you don't know what value was at memory address 8. So you won't understand the result of the computation. It's Undefined Behaviour since the program did not set the value at that address.

Comment: @MattMcNabb added note as you typed.

Comment: so assigning a value to a pointer like i did, should be avoided, right?

Comment: Not just that - it is pointless. The compiler / linker / loader assign addresss: not you.

Answer (score 2):

**1 - why is it even possible to assign a normal value (8) to a pointer (point)? aren't pointers supposed to store only addresses to other stuff? what is happening in line 8?**

You are correct that a pointer stores a memory address, but this memory address is recorded simply a number. Typically the values of pointers are much larger, but nothing stops you from assigning a pointer the memory address (8). Don't expect to use this address though. One way this is commonly used is with [NULL pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer).

```
int *point = NULL;
```

is the same as

```
int *point = 0;
```

**2- i compiled the code and for the second printf it shows : sum (28) = num (5) + point (8) why sum equals to 28? 5+8 is 13. what is happening?**

Pointer arithmetic doesn't work the way you may initially expect, as well as storing a memory location, the pointer also has a memory type:

```
int *point;
```

in this case `point` knows that it is pointing to an `int`. So when a pointer in incremented it doesn't increase it position by a single byte, it increases by `sizeof(int)` which in your case is 4 bytes. This means that `point++` or `point = point + 1` will move the pointer along by whatever size the thing it thinks it is currently pointing at is, the reason for this is to make it easy to move along an array or memory block of objects of the same type.

To get your head around this concept try messing around with this chunk of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    int * ptr = &x;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("pointer address: %p\n", ptr + i);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Specifically, try changing the type of `x` and `ptr` from `int` to `char` or `long long` and seeing the difference it makes!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is to the computer pointers are just integer value that have special meanings i.e. memory address values. Hence assigning integer values to a pointer is always possible, though you will probably end up with a null pointer.

The reason why num+pointer is 28 is because you computer is because your addresses are 32-bits in the machine you are using. So C has this feature called pointer arithmetic which means that adding/subtracting any value to a pointer will actually add 4*num since there are 4 bytes in each 32-bit word that your machine has. As a result you get point+num == 8 + (4 * 5).

=== EDIT

Just as an extra, when you do pointer arithmetic in C the machine will actually add to the pointer the number of bytes that of your datatype. For instance if you declare:

```
int num = 5;
char * point;
```

then when you do

```
point = 8;
```

the result of point + num == 8 + 5 == 13 because in most C implementations char is a single byte.

Comment: Pointers need not be integer values (although it is common that they are)

Comment: In all implementations a char is a single byte

Comment: Thinking of them as integers helps me reason about them. They are just numbers after all. I suppose one of the reasons why you say this is because memory addresses typically start from 0 (however, i know machines with signed address spaces).